# Separating a Cascade in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-shelf

I'm seeing some weird behavior in Dart. My goal is to only serve static assets if a build/web Dir exists.

1- The following works:

```
Cascade cc;
if(new Directory(buildPath).existsSync() )
{
  cc = new Cascade().add(apiHandler).add(fHandler);
} else {
  cc = new Cascade().add(apiHandler);
}
```

2- The following does not work:

```
  Cascade cc = new Cascade().add(apiHandler);
  if( new Directory(buildPath).existsSync() )
  {
    cc.add(fHandler);
  }
```

**Question**: The example in scenario 1 works fine. In the second example, when i add fHandler, how come none of its associated routes ever get handled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cascade class is immutable so the add method returns a new instance. Your second code block is assuming the current instance is modified

You need to add the cc =

```
cc = cc.add(..)
```